# Python - Como manter casas decimais de item de lista para variável?

Tags: python, spss

Estou usando Python dentro do SPSS para leitura de alguns valores dentro de um dataset. Estes valores ficam armazenados em uma lista. Estou usando 15 casas decimais e na lista os valores aparecem com 15 casas. Entretanto quando copio o valor para um variável esta armazena com até 12 casas.
Ex.
lista = [0,123456789101112, 0,987654321012345]

x = lita[0]

Quando uso x é carregado tipo 0,123456789.

Isto acontece mesmo eu utilizando: x = float(lista[0]).
A versão do Python é 2.7.6 e do SPSS 23.

Comment: Sim, pontos flutuantes tem problemas de exibição e de valores. Não há muito o que se fazer quando se trata com números desse tipo.

Comment: Recomendo a leitura dessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969 e assistir a esse vídeo: https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8

Answer (score 2):

Testei aqui com o Python 2.7 e 3.6 e o resultado foi o mesmo

```
>>> lista = [0.123456789101112, 0.987654321012345]
>>> a=lista[0]
>>> lista[0]
0.123456789101112
>>> a
0.123456789101112
```

Ou seja imprimiu o valor correrto